# Checking XML for expected structure

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I am calling a function which returns a string containing XML data. How this function works is not important but the resulting xml can be different depending on the success of the function.

Basically the function will return either the expect XML or an error formatted XML. Below are basic samples of what the two results might look like...

On Success:

```
<SpecificResult>
    <Something>data</Something>
</SpecificResult>
```

On Error:

```
<ErrorResult>
    <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorMessage>An Error</ErrorMessage>
</ErrorResult>
```

The way my system is set up is that I can convert an xml string to a class with a simple converter function but this requires my to know the class type. On success, I will know it is SpecificResult and I can convert. But I want to check to first if an error occured.

The ideal end result would allow something similar to this...

```
string xml = GetXML();
if(!IsError(xml))
{
   //convert to known type and process
}
```

So the question is, what is the best way to implement the `IsError` function?

I have thought of a couple of options but not sure if I like any of them really...

1. check if xml string contains `"<ErrorResult>"`
2. try to convert xml to ErrorResult class and check for fail
3. use XDocument or similar built in functions to parse the tree and search for ErrorResult node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `GetXml()` method is essentially returning *untyped* data and the only safe assumption here is that **it's structured as XML**, the safest way to assert its actual type would be to parse it as XML:

```
private bool IsError(string xml)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    return document.Element("ErrorResult") != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks solid enough to me. Just to make sure as msdn wasn't clear in the docs, a failed `Parse` attempt will still return an XDocument (albeit an empty one) correct? ...also, hold out for accepted answer, will wait to see if others have any input ;)

Comment: [XDocument.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) will actually [throw an XmlException if it encounters invalid XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387040.aspx). However, that sounds like a truly *exceptional* condition in this case, so you may not want to handle that in the `IsError(string)` method but rather allow the exception to propagate further up in the call chain.